# How do I parse Atom feeds using org-feed?

Tags: org-mode

I recently discovered that org comes with [org-feed](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/org/RSS-Feeds) which can be used to read RSS feeds and load their contents into an org document.  It looks like it supports Atom feeds too, but I can't seem to get it to work.  Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

```lisp
(setq org-feed-alist
      '(("Art"
         "https://nitter.net/i/lists/1399998512088064005/rss" ; RSS works
         "~/Dropbox/org/feeds.org" "Art")
        ("Charlotte Fang"
         "https://goldenlight.mirror.xyz/feed/atom"           ; Atom does not work yet
         "~/Dropbox/org/feeds.org" "Charlotte Fang"
         :parse-feed #'org-feed-parse-atom-feed
         :parse-entry #'org-feed-parse-atom-entry)
        ))

(org-feed-update-all)
```

For reference, see the docstring for [org-feed-alist](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/org/org-feed.el#L115-L186).

Comment: What problem are you running into?

Comment: OK - I've reproduced the problem. The feed looks OK (`curl -X GET` on it returns reasonable-looking stuff), but `org-feed` reports `Unavailable feed`.

Comment: Looks like a bug in `org-feed-parse-atom-feed`  - assuming that the feed is well-formatted - have you tried another reader on it? Maybe try another feed? If the feed is OK,  since `org-feed` is part of Org mode, I would report it to the Org mode ML - use `org-submit-bug-report`.

Comment: I can read the feed using the Chrome Feeder thingamajig, so it looks more and more like a bug in `org-feed-parse-atom-feed`.

Comment: @NickD - Thanks for taking a look into this.  I was hoping it was user error instead of a bug in the software, but I think your analysis is right.  I've tried Atom feeds from GitHub also, and they fail similarly with org-feed.  I think I'll follow your advice and file a bug report.